# Qt QMake - Define a string using replace function 'eval'

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm trying to refactoring some part of my .pro files.
To do that, I'm using 'eval' & 'export' QMake functions. More precisely, I'm trying to define a string to use it in source code.

```
eval(DEFINES += TEST_DEFINE=\\\"MyString\\\")
eval(export(DEFINES))
```

When I try to use TEST_DEFINE in source code, TEST_DEFINE is no longer a string...

Ex:

```
qDebug() << "Test : " << TEST_DEFINE;
```

Compilation Output:

```
use of undeclared identifier 'MyString'
```

And if I try without using eval, it's working properly:

```
DEFINES += TEST_DEFINE=\\\"MyString\\\"
```

Any ideas ? :)

Comment: what qt version are using bro? why do you need to use the "eval" function??

Comment: If it works without `eval`, why use `eval`?

Comment: Hi guys, I'm using Qt 5.15.5. And why I'm using eval ? Because I want to refactor some QMake processing in a defineReplace(MyReplaceFunction) function, and the only way I know to use defineReplace is to use it with eval/export functions.

Is it clearer ?